# Measuring the epistemic uncertainty mutual information

Tags: machine-learning, mutual-information

I possess training data denoted as $D$, a given test input denoted as $x$, and a model that is parameterized by a random variable $\theta$. This model is a neural network containing dropout layers, making it parameterized by the random variable $\theta".

My objective is to assess the model's epistemic uncertainty by quantifying the mutual information between the model parameters and the possible model outputs, represented as $y$:

$$
I(y,\theta | x,D) = H_y(y|x,D) - H_\theta(y|x,D,\theta). 
$$
Here, the entropy is labeled to indicate the specific random variable being considered.

Given that $D$ remains constant and $\theta$ depends on $D$, can we assert that $H_\theta(y|x,D,\theta) = \int p(y|x,D,\theta) p(\theta|D) d\theta = \mathbb{E}_{\theta|D} p(y|x,D,\theta)$?

In essence, I aim to evaluate how uncertain the model's predictions are by examining the relationship between its parameters and the potential outcomes, considering the inherent variability introduced by dropout layers.